# What to do with "unanswerable" questions?

Tags: discussion

https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44416/f-1-visa-expiry I would wager noone can answer this question. Searching something as big as the immihelp forum, this came up once, perhaps twice (no answers of course) and short of an immigration lawyer or an USCIS official showing up by some miracle this question will rot there forever raising the "questions with no upvoted or accepted answers" counter -- travel currently is the second most answered site among those that have >10K questions (http://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered) and I would like to keep it that way :)

Comment: I voted to delete the F1 visa question, and I will do the same to all other unanswerable old questions.

Comment: On what grounds? OK, this one was immigration but in general?

Comment: I voted to _DELETE_ the question, not to close it. It will be there forever as you said and it is already closed, questions like that can be deleted (if 3 or 5 (forgot) votes for that)... I think it is for people with 10k..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good question, there are a lot of questions that potentially have no answer, because they are too precise. And even if the OP can answer his own question once it happened, in many cases this does not mean it will happen the same way for other people (typically in the case of crossing borders as being allowed to enter a country depends on the border agent)

But that's also why there is this website in the first place. We do not like the questions that requires no more than using a search engine and pick a trustable source in the search results. There are a lot of things happening to people that are just not in the FAQ of regular websites like an embassy's.

So my answer is yes, it will grow up the list of unanswered questions. With the answerathons launched in February and March, we got to dig in the old unanswered questions and some are just forgotten or could be at least partially answered. And having an unanswered question today does not mean there will never be any answer.

And as you said, the list is apparently pretty short, this means most questions can be answered in the first place. I am not worried about that list.